# GitHub receives push but unable to create pull request

Tags: git, github

I use `git add .` → `git commit -m "commit message"` → `git push` and GitHub receives the push successfully:
[image]

However when I click on it it just show the diff and nothing else. I cannot merge it in to my main branch:
[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should always commit before pushing, otherwise your changes won't be recorded, look here for more info https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: yes I have used `git add .`, `git commit -m "commit message"` before `git push`

Comment: It seems like GitHub is not taking your commits, the UI only shows 1 commit (first picture)

Comment: Oh, I get it. You set up the repo base as "main" but are now committing on "master". You should commit on main or merge the commit from master

Comment: in the second image it's the master pointing at main. Does that mean I'm merging the commit from master to main?

Comment: Yes, merging there should fix it

Comment: but how do I do that? There seems to be no button to click

Comment: Since the repo seems to be empty, it would probably be better to just delete it and create a new one without the "main" and "master" difference (which is ambiguous) and start committing there on the base branch

Comment: yes I can do that, but I also want to know what I did wrong there. Or is it a bug from GitHub?

Comment: Probably a misconfiguration. "Master" is the old default branch name, while "main" is the new one. It can be that GitHub used "main" as default branch when creating the repo and then git used "master" (which can also be a default) to commit.

Answer (score 0):

You have committed push to master branch , however github is showing main branch as default so i think you should change it to the master branch where you pushed